# What is the significance of episode title's "The Secret of Spoons"?

Tags: analysis, title, american-gods

*American Gods* S01E02 is titled *"The Secret of Spoons"* but what is the significance of that title. I don't remember anything secret being there in that episode. Is it some nod to the source material or a hint to the god/goddesses of that episode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [wikia notes](http://americangods.wikia.com/wiki/The_Secret_of_Spoons):

> The title of the episode is in reference to an "old" song about stirring coffee that Czernobog sings while he's playing checkers with Shadow.
>
> > My love made the sweetest coffee
> >     With no sugar at all
> >     She only stirred with her spoon and it was done
> >     Now my drink is bitter
> >     The secret of spoons forgotten
> >     When my voice breaks on this song
> >     Remember old love gone
> >     And drink bitter coffee

Showrunners Bryan Fuller and Michael Green [explain the title's meaning](http://ew.com/tv/2017/05/07/american-gods-episode-2-bryan-fuller-michael-green/) to Entertainment Weekly:

> **ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY:** The episode’s title, “The Secret of Spoons,” is
>   a lyric we hear in Czernobog’s song during checkers. What does it
>   mean?
>
> **MICHAEL GREEN:** We wanted to make that last scene where they play
>   checkers as rich and cinematic as possible, and we had this idea that
>   he might sing while doing it. We thought a lot about where they came
>   from and what the type of music was—these sort of atonal, off-tempo
>   folk songs—and the idea of immigrants and what you choose to bring
>   with you in your small beliefs.
>
> A personal story: We were in the
>   middle of writing this when I woke up one morning and was thinking
>   about it while making coffee. I have this sugar bowl and spoon from my
>   favorite aunt who passed away a few years ago, and before she died, I
>   told her son, kind of jokingly but not, that if she ever passed away,
>   I wanted to remember her by the sugar bowl and spoon. And sure enough,
>   he sent it to me. It had been with her for decades and was given to
>   her when she was a child, and when you went to her house, she made you
>   coffee and would use these spoons. So, these things just sort of go
>   down in history in a family.
>
> And then we showed [music supervisor]
>   Brian Reitzell the lyrics that we were interested in and said, “Can
>   you write us a song?” And he wrote us this tune that we had stuck in
>   our head for weeks after. It was so charming and small, yet timeless,
>   and regionally correct, and quite beautiful.